# Highlight part of the bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

How do I highlight specific part of the bitmap that selected by mouse? The highlighted part will be showed in different color. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

[image: The highlight specific part of bitmap are something like the picture shown]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created a bitmap but I do not know how to hightlight it. Do you have anyway to highlight the part of the bitmap? If possible show some sample of code. Thanks

Comment: WPF? Winforms? Mono? Metro? ASP.NET?

Comment: c# window form. I have created a bitmap as a user control.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing about "highlighting" either on images or controls is that you need to gain access to a graphics object.  To get one for a bitmap you can do:

```
g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 100, 100);
g.Dispose();
```

Here is some code that uses the same principle but with a picturebox control in order to work with mouse movements in C#.

```
private bool expanding;
private bool selectActive = false;
private Point selectStart;
private Point selectPosition;
private bool selecting;
private bool selectionExists;
private bool manualFinding;


private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!selectActive)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        selectStart = e.Location;
        selecting = true;
    }

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (selecting)
    {
        selectPosition = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int x = Math.Min(selectStart.X, selectPosition.X);
    int y = Math.Min(selectStart.Y, selectPosition.Y);
    int w = Math.Abs(selectStart.X - selectPosition.X);
    int h = Math.Abs(selectStart.Y - selectPosition.Y);
    if (selectionExists || selecting)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x, y, w, h);
    }

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!selecting)
    {
        return;

    }

    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        selecting = false;
        selectionExists = true;
    }

}
```

Here is a different example of how you might create a control that can draw an image, but then where you can draw arbitrary stuff on top of the image during each invocation of the paint event:

```
public class ImageControl : Control
{
    [Description("The base image for this control to render.")]
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override paint so that it uses your glow regardless of when it is instructed to draw
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pevent"></param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        pevent.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, 0, 0, Width, Height);
        pevent.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not have a pictureBox. I use bitmap as a usercontrol. Is that the code still can apply?

Comment: I create the bitmap like this:

waveGraphics = CreateGraphics();
                waveBitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                waveGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(waveBitmap);
waveGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, 100, 100);

Comment: Er.. I don't think a bitmap can actually be a user control, but the code from your comment would draw a blue diagonal line across the bitmap so that wherever you are displaying the bitmap you would now see drawn on top of that bitmap a blue line.  But it would be better to create a custom control and override the OnPaint method, for instance.  That would let you use the same original image, but then draw blue lines or whatever on top each time the control is drawn.

Comment: If you are using the bitmap as a back-buffer, then it is ideal to draw anything that would render slowly onto the bitmap and then just render your bitmap during the OnPaint method of the control.

Comment: Ok. I get it. So the code above should be working right?

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Ted´s answer, here are my two cents.

If you want to highlight certain area inside a bitmap I would draw a semi-transparent rectangle. You can achieve that creating a `SolidBrush()` with a RGB color using the alpha channel.

```
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(waveBitmap))
    {
        // Paint transparent black mask
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0)), 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
```

So, with this code `Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0)` you create a black color (RGB `0,0,0`) with alpha value (transparency) of `100` (values goes from 0 to 255, where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is opaque).